# Config for find url in html content

Tags: search, sphinx

Can anybody help me to configure Sphinx for best matching url (part of url) in html content?

My config:

```
index base_index
{
    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 0
    morphology      = none
    min_word_len    = 3
    charset_type    = utf-8
    charset_table   = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, a..z
    enable_star     = 1
    blend_chars     = _, -, @, /, .
    html_strip      = 0
}
```

I use SphinxAPI on backend (PHP) with SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED mode.

I don't understand how search works. If I find "domain.com" I have 37 results. If "www.domain.com" - 643 results. But why? The "domain.com" is needle of "www.domain.com" and in theory with first query a have to get more results.

FreeBSD 9.2. Sphinx 2.1.2

16 distributed indexes (147Gb)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but here's my thoughts anyway.

It looks like when you search `www.domain.com`, sphinx is actually looking for `www` `domain` and `com` respectively. If you're searching for just `domain.com`, it's just looking for `domain` and `com`. This is probably the reason why `www.domain.com` returns more results, because `www` appears more frequently throughout the index.

Since you're searching URLs, I would setup [stopwords](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/conf-stopwords.html) depending on how you want to search. For me, I would make `www` `com` `org` and basically all top-level domains stopwords. You might want to leave the top-level domains and just make `www` a stopword. This would allow you to weight `com` higher than a `net` in a search result.

If you setup your stopwords right, when someone searches `domain.com` sphinx actually just looks for hits of `domain` in the index, whether it be `domain.com` or `domain.org` or `domain.net`.